# JavaFX8 - sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger not found Exception in NetBeans 8

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-8, netbeans-8

I have recently installed JDK8 + Netbeans8 (downloaded the bundled setup from Oracle site) on my Windows 8.1 machine.

When I create a very simple JavaFX FXML application, it works fine. However when I add a new database entity class using the wizard and compile it, I get following stack trace:

```
Note: Creating non-static metadata factory ...
error: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger not found


An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger not found
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1173)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:859)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:381)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:370)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:361)
at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:56)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1153)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:930)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.JavacTask.execute(JavacTask.java:145)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger not found
C:\Users\AJQ\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFX8App\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3438: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\AJQ\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFX8App\nbproject\build-impl.xml:924: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\AJQ\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFX8App\nbproject\build-impl.xml:264: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

However, if I comment out the annotations in the entity class or change the target platform from 1.8 to 1.7, application gets compiled without any issue.

Is it some bug in NetBeans 8 or some other configuration issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have the same platform (netbeans 8.0 and JDK 8), searching in other project (build in netbeans 7.4 and JDK 7) I found a little difference in the project.properties file, search it in <>/nbproject, look for the line:

```
javac.processorpath=\
    ${javac.classpath}:\
    ${libs.eclipselinkmodelgen.classpath}
```

and change the text to finally be the following:

```
javac.processorpath=\
    ${javac.classpath}
```

thats all, I don't know if it's a bug in netbeans 8 or maybe it's something wrong in the way to make the project, but this fix work for me, more details in this [blog entry](http://tutoriales.stock-zero.com/2014/05/javafx-y-jpa-problemas.html) (spanish version)

Answer (score 33):

1. Right Click on the project and select "**Properties**".
2. Select "**Libraries**" from opened "**Project Properties window**".
3. Select "**Processor**" tab.
4. Remove EclipseLink from there.
5. Apply the changes and do a **Clean Build**.

That's it. :)

Answer (score 5):

For Maven projects, setting the bootclasspath for the compiler plugin fixes the problem:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, I checked what imolero said at the project.property file and is exactly as he said is the solution, so I have to change nothing in it.

I realized that each time I worked in a JavaFX project the java files are not compiled automatically when save the file, so I made manually (F9), and re-run the project and every thing works fine. I tried to set Compile on Save in the project properties, but is shadowed, that´s the reason that I have to do it manually. My enviroment is: Windows 7 Professional 64 bits, JDK 1.8.0, Netbeans 8.0 (Build 201403101706)