# Getting an error after I changed a processpath of my project properties

Tags: java, jpa

I am currently studying JPA, for now I am making a simple login system. Now I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562797/javafx8-sun-util-logging-platformlogger-not-found-exception-in-netbeans-8) which instructed me to delete part of the project properties. But after I have deleted the said line of code I get this error after re-building or running my project:

```
Executing C:\Users\LRC-01\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JPA Login Demo\dist\run1470478781\JPA Login Demo.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre/bin/java
Error: Could not find or load main class com.login
Java Result: 1
```

How do I solve this problem, is this some kind of a bug? The question was dated 3 years ago so I thought this was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the project and choose "Properties".

Then select "Run". There you can select the main class that NetBeans should run.